# How to output non null terminated string to iostream, but keep formatting

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to output non null terminating string, but keep iomanip formatting, e.g. std::left, std::setw etc.

My current code looks like this:

```
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const StringRef &sr){
    //return os.write(sr.data(), sr.size() );
    // almost the same, but std::setw() works
    return __ostream_insert(sr.data(), sr.size() );
}
```

This work OK on Linux with gcc, but fail on MacOS with clang.

Comment: `return os << std::string(sr.data(), sr.size());`?

Comment: And you might be interested in [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes and create string on the fly, including malloc...

StringRef is my own implementation of string_view

Comment: Then perhaps look at [how the `std::string_view` overload of `operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator_ltlt) is working and what it does?

Comment: this is how i come up to `__ostream_insert`, but i am looking for more portable approach

Comment: From the linked reference: "... stores each character ... to the output stream os as if by calling `os.rdbuf()->sputn(seq, n)`". Symbols with leading double underscore are *reserved* for the compiler and standard library, they should be considered non-portable. The linked reference also describes how to handle padding and field width. If you skip the sentry object creation, it's a detailed list that you can copy into your own code quite verbatim. If you do, then it *will* be portable.

Comment: really?!?!? so it do malloc anyway. seems string approach is not that bad after all.

Comment: No need to allocate anything if that's what you're worried about, all you need is loops and use the [`sputc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sputc) to write character by character instead (which is what's going to happen anyway).

Comment: @Nick I do not see any indication that `std::string_view` does any memory allocation.

Comment: Exactly. The whole point of std::string_view is that it is a *non-owning* reference to an array of characters.

Comment: I meant something else - if operator << uses string stream, then it do memory allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion about `os.rdbuf()->sputn(seq, n)` was certainly interesting, but it did not made the expected result.

I did open GCC C++ library code and "stole" from there. After the cleanup, code is something like this:

```
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const StringRef &sr){
    // following is based on gcc __ostream_insert() code:
    // https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.2/ostream__insert_8h-source.html

    std::streamsize const width = os.width();
    std::streamsize const size  = static_cast<std::streamsize>( sr.size() );
    std::streamsize const fill_size = width - size;

    bool const left = (os.flags() & std::ios::adjustfield) == std::ios::left;

    auto osfill = [](std::ostream& os, auto const count, char const c){
        for(std::streamsize i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            os.put(c);
    };

    if (fill_size > 0 && left == false)
        osfill(os, fill_size, os.fill());

    os.write(sr.data(), size);

    if (fill_size > 0 && left == true)
        osfill(os, fill_size, os.fill());

    return os;
}
```